# What does @input="$emit('input', $event)" means in vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-events

I am reading some code that I want to update:

```html
<b-input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event)" ref="input" :maxlength="maxlength"/>
```

what does `@input="$emit('input', $event)"` stand for?
Where and how can I listen for the input event?

Answer (score 5):

`@input` is the short-hand for `v-on:input` which binds to the component's `input` event. `vm.$emit` is documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) and has an example with a similar use-case [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event).

In your case your component simply emits an event with the same name and the same arguments as the one it receives from its child `b-input`. Programatically you can listen to these events with [`vm.$on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on), e.g. in your `mounted` method:

```
export default {
  components: { BInput },

  mounted () {
    this.$on('input', (event) => {
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$emit` is data passed to an other component, see this example:

Component: getEmit.vue

```html
<template>
  <!--get data-->
  <button-emit v-on:data="getValue"></button-emit>
</template>
<script>
  import buttonEmit from './buttonEmit'
  export default {
    name: 'getEmit',
    components: { buttonEmit },
    methods: {
      // get payload in parameter
      getValue(event) {
        alert('Get Emit Success' + event)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Component: buttonEmit.vue

```html
<template>
  <button @click="emit($event)"></button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'buttonEmit',
    methods: {
      emit(event) {
      // Emit text data the payload event
        this.$emit('data', event)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```